# Using legend with stat_function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `scale_colour_manual` to specify the possible keys in the legend. However, if I use `stat_function` to plot custom function, the legend is missing.

Any ideas why this happen?

```
library(ggplot2)

MyFun <- function(x, p) {
  res <- x^(1 / p)
  return(res)
}

my.df <-data.frame(x = c(0,1))
plt <- ggplot(my.df, aes(x=x)) +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 10), colour = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 3), colour = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 2), colour = "green") +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 1), colour = "orange") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"))

print(plt)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Put `colour=` inside the `aes()` and then provide name for particular line as is should appear in legend. Legend is made for aesthetics that are only inside `aes()` call.

```
ggplot(my.df, aes(x=x)) +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 10), aes(colour = "line1")) +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 3), aes(colour = "line2")) +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 2), aes(colour = "line3")) +
  stat_function(fun = MyFun, n = 1000, args = list(p = 1), aes(colour = "line4")) +
  scale_colour_manual("Lgend title", values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"))
```

[image]